# Select the first row among the visible rows in grid after filter operation

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to select the first the first row among the visible rows in grid after filter operation

I tried to follow the code in following post but it doest not satisfy the condition of current cell ...

[DataGridView: How to select first cell in current row when MultiSelect is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787743/datagridview-how-to-select-first-cell-in-current-row-when-multiselect-is-true)

I tried following code but it is not working

1:

```
if (grdGLSearch.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible) > 0)
   grdGLSearch.Rows[0].Cells[0].Selected  = true;
```

or 2:

```
if (grdGLSearch.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible) > 0)
   foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in grdGLSearch.Rows[0].Cells)
   {
      cell.Selected = true;
      return;
   }
```

Comment: You said  "I want to select the first (visible) row in a grid " then you tried to Selected one Cell. Please give me the correct scenario

Comment: i Edited my question accordingly ....

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in grdGLSearch.Rows)
            {
                if (item.Visible)
                {
                    item.Selected = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

if (grdGLSearch.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible) > 0)

```
  grdGLSearch.Select(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Property **SelectionMode** to Select **FullRowSelect**.

use this Code

```
grdGLSearch.Rows[0].Selected = true;
```

Comment: This does not work as intended in the case where Row [0] has its .Visible property set to false.  Perhaps you need to re-read the question.